# Webpack, как принудительно вынести модуль в отдельный build layer?

Tags: сборка, webpack

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас разбираюсь в вебпаке и возникли проблемы с неким тестовым примером.
Схема зависимостей прилагается.

Чего я хочу - вынести External lib B в некий отдельный слой сборки, притом так чтобы ее не надобыло подключать в html дополнительно (т.е externals не подходят насколько я понимаю). То есть так, чтобы она грузилась ondemand, когда мы запрашиваем модуль Y или модуль Z, и ее не нужно было грузить второй раз.

При дефолтных настройках сборки у нас будут два куска: (Y+B+A) и (Z+B). Я хочу три: (Y+A), Z, B

Видимо мне надо использовать CommonsChunkPlugin, но по докам воспроизвести пока не удается.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var CommonsPlugin = new require("webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./main"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [
            "."
        ]
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "js/",
        filename: "[name].builded.js"
    },
    plugins: [
           new CommonsPlugin({
            //  Что написать сюда?
            })
    ]
};
```